# Is there a mime-type that is invalid by definition?

Tags: http, mime-types, content-type

I am writing an http middleware using Node.js that responds to requests with a certain content-type set as header. Now I'd like to unit test that the middleware does not respond to requests with the "wrong" content-type.

Of course, I can basically use *any* content-type for this that is not intended to be supported by my component, but I was wondering whether there is a content-type that is intended to be used in this cases (similar to the domain [example.com](http://www.iana.org/domains/example) which is for illustrative purposes only and can be used in documentation.

Is there something such as `content/invalid` or something like this?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types. How about `lfdjkgndflg/sldkmsdfqwfd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no. You can have a "personal" or "vanity" mime type by prepending with prs. [Media Type Specification, Personal/Vanity type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-3.3)...but there is no mime that is, by definition, invalid. There are obsolete and deleted ones, but they are not by definition invalid.

So you can pretty much do whatever you want, such as `content/prs.golo.impossibru` or use an oxymoron, like `content/swift-government-action` - or whatever. It's kind of like how in some languages 'foo' and 'bar' are such common example variable names, where in other languages that just isn't done. In mime types there just appears to be no such convention.

This is at least partially because its almost never the mime type that is invalid, because if an error will occur it's usually that the mime is one thing but the content actually sent does not match it.

Answer (score 0):

There are (infinitely) many that can address what’s described in the question body* and the intuition that “example” would be the key was spot on. They’re called [Example Media Types (RFC 4735)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4735.html).

### Top level registration tree example media types: `example/*`

The example media types take two forms. The first is a top-level “example” registration tree. It was [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#examples) for the express purpose of forbidding registration of any subtype in that tree, so no matter what the subtype is — `example/foo`, `example/bar+json`, etc — it’s defined as being valid for use in examples only.

The IANA registry’s second note about the `example` tree claims the misuse of an example media type in a context where a real media type is expected is “an error” — and the example it gives is the same scenario that motivated this question (italics added):

> The occurrence of an 'example' media type as a media type outside of examples, e.g. *in a Content-Type header,* is an error [...]

This is consistent with what RFC 4735 says:

> The 'example' media subtypes are defined for use in documentation only. They MUST NOT be implemented. Their appearance in real code could lead to unpredictable results and therefore open up security holes. Interoperability considerations: Any attempt to negotiate or send one of these 'example' media subtypes is bound to lead to interoperability problems.

### Registered example subtypes in other top-level registration trees

The other kind of example media type takes the form `<...>/example`, but the possible values for `<...>` are effectively hard-coded, unfortunately. RFC4735 stopped short of normative updates that could have future-proofed this part of the idea, instead using the same “register it but define it as forever fake” solution for the subtypes as the top-level type. That means there’s no guarantee** that an `example` subtype has example semantics, only that the following ones do:

- `application/example`
- `audio/example`
- `image/example`
- `message/example`
- `model/example`
- `multipart/example`
- `text/example`
- `video/example`

Apart from `example` itself only one top-level registration tree has been added since that time, `font`, but it does illustrate the problem: `font/example` is (in theory) not an example media type, just an unregistered media type.

Though any given external application is unlikely to treat `example/duckling` differently from `quack/quack`, your own application is free to handle them distinctly. As the RFC pointed out, receiving `example` in open interchange could hint at real issues on the sender side.

---

* I’m phrasing it that way because the title of the question says “invalid”, but there are different notions of [“valid media/MIME types”](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-mime-type) that are equally authoritative in their appropriate contexts. Often it only refers to (an) idea of syntactic validity, but if that’s all you needed, you could use any string at all without a "/" and be done.

** Though it’s probably silly to worry about; I would hope that the IANA wouldn’t actually permit `font/example` to be registered with non-example semantics given the idea was so clearly to reserve them all.